# Assign array to be equal to another array

Tags: php

Currently I am building Paypal Payment with REST API, and I want to assign array value to another one

```
        //Data for Options
        $data = [
            'payer' => [
                "address" => [
                    "address_line_1" => "Test",
                    "admin_area_2" => "Test",
                    "postal_code" => "111",
                    "admin_area_1" => "Test",
                    "country_code" => "GB"
                ]
            ],

            'amountObject' => [
                "currency_code" => "EUR",
                "value" => $this->orderPrice
            ],

            'purchase_units' => [
                "object" => [

                     //Equals to amountObject array 
                    "amount" => "amountObject"
                ],

                "shipping" => [
                     //Equals to payer['address']
                    "address" => "payer['address']"
                ]
            ],

            'intent' => 'CAPTURE'
        ];
```

So what I want to archive is that `Purchase Units -> object -> amount` is equal to **amountObject array**, and `shipping-> address` is equal to **payer['address']**
Thanks for help

Comment: You would need to do multiple assignment operations to do this, or prepare the sub values before hand and then reference that separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

The second issue might be solved by this:

```
$data['purchase_units']['shipping']['address'] = $data['payer']['address']
```

I think that is probably what ChristianM was thinking of in the comment.

The first issue would probably be similar although I am not quite sure what the `$this` is all about.